# is there a way to convert a string with numbers to a list of numeric values?

Tags: r, list

Supose I have the following

```
X <- "1,2,3,4,5"
```

How do I get the sequence of numeric values

```
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

I've already seen this example https://statisticsglobe.com/convert-character-to-numeric-in-r/ But it doesn't quite match with the problem above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of doing this:

```
library(stringr)

l="1,2,3,4,5"
as.numeric(str_split(l, ',', simplify = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** scan will convert such a string to a numeric vector.  Omit the quiet argument if you would like it to report the length of the result. No packages are used.

```
x <- "1,2,3,4,5"
scan(text = x, sep = ",", quiet = TRUE)
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

**2)** If what you have is actually a vector of comma separated character stings. xx. and a list of numeric vectors is wanted then lapply over them.

```
xx <- c(x, x)
lapply(xx, function(x) scan(text = x, sep = ",", quiet = TRUE))
## [[1]]
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```